# Is there some way to validate redux-form in a custom input?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I need to throw a validation error from my custom input component, and not let the user successfully submit the form. In this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-forked-ns1f2?file=/SimpleForm.js), I'm passing the `maxLength` prop to the `Field` with a custom input component `RenderField`. I want to validate the `maxLength` within the `RenderField` (see the comments in the Codesandbox).

Some observations:

- I can't pass a validate prop to the `Field`, neither at `reduxForm` decorator. This is due to an architecture decision.
- The max length example at the Sandbox is only to illustrate what I need. I know I can pass `maxLength` to the input component if I need to validate it, but my real problem is not about a string's max length.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will fit your needs but you can add your validation rules into `onSubmit` function which in your case is `showResults`

```
export default (async function showResults(values) {
  await sleep(500); // simulate server latency

  const { firstName } = values;

  if (firstName.length < 5)
    throw new SubmissionError({ firstName: "too short" });

  window.alert(`You submitted:\n\n${JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}`);
});
```

then you can clean up the `RenderField`

```
const RenderField = ({
  input,
  placeholder,
  type,
  maxLength,
  meta: { error, dispatch, ...restMeta },
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        {...input}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        style={{ border: 0, width: "100%" }}
      />
      <p>{error}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Line below won't work because it is mutation, I don't see action creator which will be able to handle this properly.

```
if (errorMessage) error = errorMessage;
```

Also you can consider to track state of the button and show errors only if it was clicked.

But IMO the best solution would be really to handle validation in `redux-form`.

Comment: Yes, you're right this is another way to validate. But still not what I need, though :( Anyway, thanks for answering!